# Difference between two vectors and new vector containing elements of the same indexes of remaining vector

Tags: c++

Let us consider three vectors

```
std::vector<std::size_t> v1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
std::vector<std::size_t> v2{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
std::vector<std::size_t> const v3{7, 10}
```

where `v2` always has the same size of `v1`. I want to have a vector `v4` that is the difference between `v2` and `v3`, that is, `v4 = {6, 8, 9}`. Besides, I want to have a vector `v5` that contains the elements of the remaining indexes of `v2` in `v4`, that is, `v5 = {1, 3, 4}`. In this example, the remaining elements of `v2` in `v4` are `v2[0]`, `v2[2]`, and `v2[3]`, this way, `v5 = {v1[0], v1[2], v[3]}`.

By now, I have the [working code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PsfdvWdW8)

```
std::vector<std::size_t> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<std::size_t> v2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
std::vector<std::size_t> const v3 = {10, 7};

std::vector<int> v4;
std::vector<int> v5;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
{
    if (std::find(v3.begin(), v3.end(), v2[i]) == v3.end())
    {
        v4.push_back(v2[i]);
        v5.push_back(v1[i]);
    }
}
```

Although the code is working, I am wondering if there is any algorithm in `std` that is faster and do the same job.

P.S.: neither `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` has repeated elements. `v3` is defined as `const` because it cannot be modified (obviously, a copy of it can be made, but more memory will be required; `v3` as well as `v1` and `v2` can have more than 1e6 elements). `v2`, and so `v1`, is always bigger than `v3`. The solution can be based on `c++20`.

I know that there is `std::set_difference` from `algorithm`, but it just defines `v4`. For building `v5`, I will need to find the indexes of the removed elements of `v4` and then remove these elements from `v1`.

Comment: Don't spam tags! What specific to each C++ version is in your question?

Comment: Sounds like you need some combination of `std::set_intersection`, `std::set_difference`, and `std::set_symmetric_difference`

Comment: from your description ist not clear what `v1` is good for. `v4` is set_difference between `v2` and `v3` and `v5` is indices of those elements, but what about `v1` ? It doesnt appear in your text other than "where v2 always has the same size of v1"

Comment: when you need indices of elements in the orginial vector you can first turn your original vector into `std::vector<std::pair<int,size_t>>` where `first` is the element and `second` is the index. Then do all transformations on the pairs. In the end `second` is the index in the original vector

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, `v2` is built on top of `v1`, that's why they always will have the same size.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I am afraid I didn't understand what you mean. Do you mind providing a simple code?

Comment: are all input vectors sorted?

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing. I think you have a typo here " I want to have a vector v5 that contains the elements of the remaining indexes of v2" because in your code you actually do use `v1`  for `v5`

Comment: @MarekR, not necessarily.

Comment: if you sort them you can save a lot of `find`. First you can use  `binary_search` and then you dont have to search the whole vector with the next call to `binary_search`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I edited the question and explain better the relation between `v5` and `v1`.

Comment: All the algorithms and containers in the C++ library are basic, straightforward algorithms and containers. All the algorithms [are listed here, for example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). If you don't see your algorithm listed there, it does not exist.

Comment: Is `v1` always just the list of indices? Is `v2` and `v3` sorted?

Comment: You would sort `v2` and `v3` and iterate over both at the same time (single non-nested loop), the algorithm would otherwise be similar to what you posted.

Comment: @Sebastian, `v1` is not a list of indexes. `v2` and `v3` are not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Which is typically larger? `v2` or `v3`?

Comment: @Sebastian, `v2` is always bigger than `v3`.

Comment: You can use binary search, if `v3` is sorted. Then the searches including sort take `O((v3size + v2size) * log v3size)` instead of `O(v2size * v3size)` time.

Comment: See `binary_search` in Sam's link. You want the functions, which test for existence to replace the `find` in your code.

Comment: The last example on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search is quite similar in structure.

Comment: The needles would be`v2` and the haystack `v3_sorted`.

Comment: There would be a possible small performance improvement to reserve some initial space in`v4` and `v5`, so they do not have to be repeatedly copied to larger space, when the vectors get full.

Comment: "v3 is defined as const because it can be modified" - Certainly you mean because it *cannot* be modified. Right?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yes, you are right. It was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, but the first paragraph is still not clear. The only mention of `v1` is that it has the same size as `v2`, and then suddenly "...this way, v5 = {v1[0], v1[2], v[3]}."   `v` is a typo, and before you write "v5 that contains the elements of the remaining indexes of v2 in v4," no mention of v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we first create a map of values in `v2` to their corresponding values in `v1`, then it's very straightforward to get those values from `v1` back in `v5`.

`operator[]` in a `std::map` is O(log n) and `std::set_difference` is O(m + n) (where the variables are the lengths of the two vectors), while `std::find` is O(n), so this should be more efficient in terms of runtime complexity.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

using std::size_t;

int main() {
    std::vector<size_t> v1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<size_t> v2{6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::vector<size_t> v3{7, 10};
 
    std::vector<size_t> v4;
    std::vector<size_t> v5;

    std::map<size_t, size_t> m;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        m[v2[i]] = v1[i];
    }

    std::set_difference(
        v2.begin(), v2.end(),
        v3.begin(), v3.end(),
        std::back_inserter(v4)
    );

    std::transform(
        v4.begin(), v4.end(),
        std::back_inserter(v5),
        [&](auto v) { return m[v]; }
    );

    for (auto x : v5) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation to practice use of ranges and C++23:

```cpp
using V = std::vector<int>;

auto magicFilter(const V& values, const V& keys, const V& filterKeys)
{
    const std::unordered_set<int> filterSet { filterKeys.begin(), filterKeys.end() };
    using namespace std::views;
    return zip(values, keys)
        | filter([&filterSet](const auto& x) {
              return !filterSet.contains(get<1>(x));
          })
        | elements<0>
        | std::ranges::to<V>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PjcbWP5ev